# Not giving the right answer when putting the largest number at first position of the list

Tags: python, user-defined-functions

```
def get_second_largest(nums):
    largest = nums[0]
    second_largest = nums[0]
    for i in range(1, len(nums)):
        if nums[i] > largest:
            second_largest = largest
            largest = nums[i]
        elif nums[i] > second_largest:
            second_largest = nums[i]
    return second_largest
my_nums = [8,11,29,25,76,12]
second_largest = get_second_largest(my_nums)
print("Second largest number is,",second_largest)
```

In this program, we get the second largest number as output but the problem is when we put the largest number of the list at first position(my_nums[0]),
It gives us the largest number as output saying second-largest number.

Ex:
Input: list1 = [44,21,34,18,26],
Output: Second largest number is, 44

How can I solve this bug(I don't know it's called bug or not, I'm a beginner)?

Note: What I figured out is if I can make the computer understand that
after all those calculations if largest == second largest:
find the largest number in range(1,len(nums)),
And this range's largest number is the second largest number of the list. How and where to write this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will do nothing when largest number is in first position. Just change your 3d line to this:

```
second_largest = 0
```

Full code:

```
def get_second_largest(nums):
    largest = nums[0]
    second_largest = min(nums)
    for i in range(1, len(nums)):
        if nums[i] > largest:
            second_largest = largest
            largest = nums[i]
        elif nums[i] > second_largest:
            second_largest = nums[i]
    return second_largest
my_nums = [100,8,11,29,25,76,12]
second_largest = get_second_largest(my_nums)
print("Second largest number is,",second_largest)

76
```

Comment: Thanks, this was really a smart solution. :)

Answer (score 2):

You start by setting `largest` and `second_largest` to the largest element value (the first one in this case):

```
largest = nums[0]
second_largest = nums[0]
```

Unfortunately, that means the expressions:

```
nums[i] > largest
nums[i] > second_largest
```

will *never* be true, so `second_largest` will never change from its initial (largest) value.

If you still want to use your current method, this would be better:

```
def get_second_largest(nums):
    # Return none if list not big enough.

    if len(nums) < 2: return None

    # Get largest and second largest from first two (possible swap).

    largest = nums[0]
    second_largest = nums[1]
    if largest < second_largest:
        (largest, second_largest) = (second_largest, largest)

    # Process all others.

    for i in range(2, len(nums)):
        if nums[i] > largest:
            (second_largest, largest) = (largest, nums[i])
        elif nums[i] > second_largest:
            second_largest = nums[i]
    return second_largest

print(f"Second largest number is {get_second_largest([8,11,29,25,76,12])}")
```

Most of the code in that function is the same except for the way you initialise (from first two elements rather than just the first).

---

Of course, a more Pythonic way would be:

```
def get_second_largest(nums):
    # None if too small, else second last element of sorted items.

    if len(nums) < 2: return None
    return sorted(nums)[-2]
```

If you're learning *algorithms,* then the long-winded approach is probably better. However, if your goal is to learn *Python,* this shorter one is preferable, since it's usually better to just use the aspects of the language that make your life a lot easier.

---

And, just as an aside, you may want to think about what second largest mean in the context of the list `[3, 3, 2, 1]` (for example).

Your current code (and therefore mine as well) states that `3` is the second largest but that may not *necessarily* be the best definition - it *could* be considered to be `2` (the second largest *value* (with no duplicates) as opposed to the second largest item). Not saying either way is the right way, just that you may want to consider it.

If *that* is the definition of second largest you want to use, a slight modification will take care of that, using a collection with duplicates removed before-hand:

```
def get_second_largest_no_dupes(nums):
    # De-dupe, then None or second last sorted element.

    num_set = set(nums)
    if len(num_set) < 2: return None
    return sorted(num_set)[-2]
```

Comment: What a beautiful way of answering! Thank you so much.

Comment: If `1` is returned as the second largest element from `[1, 1, 2, 3]` then something has horribly gone wrong ;)

Comment: I saw it gives 2 as second largest number, which is correct. Maybe, he meant something else.

Comment: @ack, I was all set to explain the difference to you between the second highest *element* and second highest *value,* when I suddenly got what you were saying. Silly me, I've now changed it so it uses the correct definition of "highest", not the definition that means "lowest" :-)